# update select box when div is click with same id and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list of size and quantity that is inside the select box and a table, 
everytime the user select on size and quantity the table is being highlighted

here is the jsfiddle link for my code

http://jsfiddle.net/19ehdn54/9/

what i want to do now is when user try to click on the table list the select box of size and quantity should change also, i've tried adding this code

```
$('#qty2 td').click(function() {
    $('#qty2 .highlight td').removeClass('highlight2')
        var textvalue = this.id;
    $('select#size').val(textvalue).change();

});
```

the select box for sizes is updating but the quantity is not, and only the bottom table part is  clickable,

any help is much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: you code is not working for change also in fiddle

Comment: sorry, here's the correct link http://jsfiddle.net/19ehdn54/9/

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer to this and add this code

```
jQuery('#qty2 td').click(function() {
    var e = jQuery(this);
    var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var parentID  =  jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');

   //remove class attribute to td
   jQuery('#qty2 td').removeAttr('class');

   //set highlight class to clicked column
   e.addClass('highlight2');

   jQuery('#size').val(elementID);
   jQuery('#qty').val(parentID);
});
```